# Changing group in shell

Tags: files, group, access-control

Simple enough.
I have user foo.
foo belongs to groups foo (main), audio, A, B and *common*.

Normally files are created with ownership foo.foo.

For a while I would like foo to create files with group *common*.
Basically I see it this way:

```
Cache present group
Change group to *common*
Touch alpha
Touch beta 
...
Change group back.
```

alpha beta ( and anything after ) should be created with owner foo.*common*.
How can I accomplish this?

PS:
Oops. Forgot to say that I want to do this in both bash and zsh.

Comment: Did your file be stored in a *common* directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither bash nor zsh has this functionality.

You can call [`newgrp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/newgrp.1.html). This is an external command, which starts a new process. It runs the program indicated by the `SHELL` environment variable with no arguments.

```
newgrp common <<EOS
touch alpha beta
EOS
touch belongs_to_original_group
```

Note that since `newgrp` starts a new shell, it doesn't inherit from the shell variables of the original shell, only from environment (exported) variables. Any assignments performed there will take effect only there.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, use the [`newgrp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/newgrp.1.html) command:

```
newgrp common
touch whatever
newgrp foo
```

Since you are a member of both groups (and probably used no password for the groups), you should be able to switch readily.  Actually each call to `newgrp` makes a subshell.  You can check "who" you are using **[`id`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/id.1.html)**.  Whether you exit from a shell (and resume the previous group) or create a new subshell depends on what you want to do.

Unlike some of the related commands, this one is in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/newgrp.html):

> The newgrp utility shall create a new shell execution environment with a new real and effective group identification.

Comment: That's half. How do I  change back?

Comment: No, this isn't how `newgrp` works. It starts a new shell, which will be interactive if stdin is a terminal. `touch whatever` would be executed when that shell exits.

Comment: @Gilles I guess this depends on whether you use `newgrp` inside a script or interactively. In the first case you have to actually pass the commands to `newgrp` via STDIN. But if you are in an interactive shell, `newgrp common` will just run a new interactive shell and `touch whatever` will than be typed into the new shell and run with the changed group settings.

Comment: @TLOlczyk you can also just leave the interactive shell opened by `newgrp common` with `exit` and it will drop you back into the original shell session. Running `newgrp foo` will actually open another interactive shell, so that you now would have three shells running.

Answer (score 0):

If the files under consideration are not scattered over too many directories, then you can even automate the process by using a subtle feature of Unix permissions, namely the SGID-bit for directories.

Suppose a directory has permissions 2775 (say), which is `rwxrwsr-x` and is owned by `xyz.common`. If a user who is member of group `common` creates a file or subdirectory in this directory, then its group ownership is automatically set to `common`.